# Errors with custom class UIButton in Swift 4.2. What's new with UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, swift4.2

I have the following code

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.theme_setTitleColor(GlobalPicker.customButtonTextColor, forState: .normal)
        self.theme_setTitleColor(GlobalPicker.customButtonDisabledTextColor, forState: .disabled)
        self.theme_backgroundColor = GlobalPicker.primaryColor

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/4.0
        self.clipsToBounds = true

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2.0
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

And I'm getting errors when trying to build this code with Xcode 10. The code works just fine with Xcode 9 and Swift 4.0. I was hoping for a seamless transition but apparently that's not what I'm getting.

[image]

Is this an Xcode 10 bug? Anyone else running into anything similar?

Comment: Your `CustomButton` works just fine for me in a playground in Xcode 10.0.

Comment: Can't reproduce any issue. Can you post a test project?

Comment: Also, any time you update Xcode, your first move should be: Delete all simulators, quit Xcode, empty DerivedData, throw out the cache (in Caches folder), restart computer. Did you try that?

Comment: Happens to me on both Xcode 10 GM and 10.1 Beta. Not sure what to think here... I'll see if I can post a test project with this issue.

Comment: Are you using some kind of toolchain? Maybe this is a Swift 5 thing?

Comment: Nope, and doing all of your suggestions doesn't fix the issue either. I created a small sample project and it compiles fine, but my larger more complex project (with multiple Pods, etc) with this class gives these errors. I may pass this on to Apple using one of my DTS requests to get this figured out. For now I'll continue with Xcode 9 until I can figure out what the deal is.

Comment: "but my larger more complex project (with multiple Pods, etc) with this class gives these errors" So that's the problem. You are using something that extends UIButton and wrecks it. So do a global search for `extension UIButton` and you'll find what's causing this issue.

Comment: See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2935 - an extension can wreck a built-in class, and there won't be anything about it from the compiler but the class won't work properly.

Comment: Try saying `class CustomButton: Foundation.UIButton {`. There's just a chance this will pass you around the offending extension.

Comment: Sorry, UIKit is what I meant. I'll give that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there's an `extension` somewhere in one of the targets of your project or workspace that messes with UIButton in a way that cripples it somehow. (The fact that this is possible is clear, and I regard it as a bug; see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2935 and the related duplicates, including https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3228, and mine at https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8010.)

You might be able to slide around the extension by subclassing `UIKit.UIButton` instead of simple `UIButton`. For the reason why this works, see the comment discussion in my duplicate bug report. When an extension behaves this way, it *overloads* methods, and you can distinguish the UIButton that doesn't have the overloads by using the module namespace.